# Armstrong Number Checker in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, math, integer, numbers

I am still somewhat of a beginner to Java, but I need help with my code. I wanted to write an Armstrong Number checker.

> An Armstrong number is one whose sum of digits raised to the power three equals the number itself. 371, for example, is an Armstrong number because 3^3 + 7^3 + 1^3 = 371.

If I understand this concept correctly, then my code should work fine, but I don't know where I made mistakes. I would appreciate if you could help correct my mistakes, but still kind of stick with my solution to the problem, unless my try is completely wrong or most of it needs to change.

Here is the code:

```java
public class ArmstrongChecker {
    
     boolean confirm = false;
     Integer input;
     String converter;
     int indices;
     int result = 1;
    
     void ArmstrongCheck(Integer input) {
        this.input = input;
        converter = input.toString();
        char[] array = converter.toCharArray();
        indices = array.length;
        result = (int) Math.pow(array[0], indices);
        
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            result = result + (int) Math.pow(array[i], indices);
        }
        if (result == input) {
            confirm = true;
            System.out.println(confirm);
        } else {
            System.out.println(confirm);
        }
    }
}
```

For my tries I used '153' as an input. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `array[i]` is a `char`. Ex: the char code for `'1'` is 49. You can use [`Character.getNumericValue(array[i])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)).

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you wanted/expected?

Comment: What part of this code is raising anything to the 3rd power?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to use the debugger... @ScottHunter

Comment: @ScottHunter Before the for loop I raise the first index of the number/array to the 3rd power and in the for loop, I raise the last 2 indices of the number/array to the 3rd power and everything is added together.

Comment: @ScottHunter The explanation given by OP is misleading. [Armstrong number -  is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of the number of digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) - Digits should be raised to the power that is equal to the **number of digits**, which is `3` only in the given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't summing the digits, but the numeric values of the characters representing them. You can convert such a character to its numeric value by subtracting the character `'0'`:

```java
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result = result + (int) Math.pow(array[i] - '0', indices);
}
```

Having said that, it's arguably (probably?) more elegant to read the input as an actual `int` number and iterate its digits by taking the reminder of `10` on each iteration. The number of digits itself can be calculated using a base-10 log.

```java
int temp = input;
int result = 0;
int indices = (int) Math.log10(input) + 1;
while (temp != 0) { 
    int digit = temp % 10;
    result += (int) Math.pow(digit, indices);
    temp /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small logical mistake in your code, You're not converting the character to an integer instead you're doing something like

```
Math.pow('1', 3) -> Math.pow(49, 3) // what you're doing

Math.pow(1, 3) // what should be done
```

You should first convert the character to the string using any method below

```
result = (int) Math.pow(array[0],indices);

for(int i = 1;i<array.length;i++) {
     result = result + (int) Math.pow(array[i],indices);
}
```

**For converting char to integer**

```
int x = Character.getNumericValue(array[i]);
```

**or**

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(array[i]));
```

**or**

```
int x = array[i] - '0';
```

### Alternatively

You can also check for Armstrong's number without any conversion, using the logic below

```
public class Armstrong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number = 153, num, rem, res = 0;
        num = number;

        while (num != 0)
        {
            rem = num % 10;
            res += Math.pow(rem, 3);
            num /= 10;
        }

        if(res == num)
            System.out.println("YES");
        else
            System.out.println("NO");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For any `int >= 0` you can do it like this.

Print all the Armstrong numbers less than 10_000.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
    if (isArmstrong(i)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

prints

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
153
370
371
407
1634
8208
9474
```

The key is to use `Math.log10` to compute the number of digits in the candidate number.  This must be amended by adding 1.  So `Math.log10(923)` returns `2.965201701025912`.  Casting to an `int` and adding `1` would be `3 digits`.
The number of digits is then the power used for computation.

Then it's just a matter of summing up the digits raised to that power.  The method short circuits and returns `false` if the sum exceeds the number before all the digits are processed.

```
    
public static boolean isArmstrong(int v) {

    if (v < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument must >= 0");
    }
    
    int temp = v;
    int power = (int)Math.log10(temp)+1;
    int sum = 0;
    
    while (temp > 0) {
        sum += Math.pow(temp % 10, power);
        
        if (sum > v) {
           return false;
        }

        temp/= 10;
    }
    
    return v == sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for Armstrong's number without any conversion, using the logic below for any number!!

```
package mypack;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Armstrong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number to check whether it is an Armstrong number or not:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int count;
        int temp=num;

        for(count=0;temp!=0;count++)
        {
            temp=temp/10;
        }
        int result = 0;
  for ( int mynum=num;mynum!=0;mynum=mynum/10)
  {
        int rem=mynum%10;
         result+=Math.pow(rem,count);

  }
        if (result==num) {
            System.out.println("its Armstrong number!!!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("its not Armstrong num");}

    }
}
```